# #define x 4+1....... what will be the output when cube of x is printed?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 4+1
int main()
{
     int i;
     i = x*x*x;
     printf("%d",i);
     return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

The C preprocessor will literally substitute all instances of `x` for `4+1`, resulting in the following code:

```
i = 4+1*4+1*4+1;
```

Since `*` has precedence over `+`, this evaluates to:

```
i = 4+4+4+1;
```

and `i` gets the value `13`.

Comment: +1 for it took me a while to realize how it was going. :)

@prasanthi This sure is not a good way to use define but still if you want the expected result like  `i = 5*5*5` then use the parentheses like `i = (x)*(x)*(x)`. This works because it has precedence over the other operators.

Comment: In this case, it would be better to put the parentheses in the definition, as @user2808726's answer states. However, it would be best to use an inline function, and let the optimizer do its thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use parentheses in definition like this:

```
#define x (4+1)
```

then, this evaluates to:

```
i = (4+1)*(4+1)*(4+1)
```

the value of `i` is 125